# Getting ArtifactDescriptorException: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.glassfish.jersey.media:jersey-media-moxy:jar:2.22.1

Tags: java, maven, jersey

I am following RESTFul services tutorial (javabrains.io/courses/javaee_jaxrs/lessons/Returning-JSON-Response) and was trying to return JSON response from the service end through a POJO.

I have created a maven project using jersey-quickstart-webapp archtype. I have added "jersey-media-moxy" in pom.xml for JSON support and when the update was happening, I could see the below error in Eclipse Markers tab. Does any one have idea on how to resolve this issue.

> ArtifactDescriptorException: Failed to read artifact descriptor for
>   org.glassfish.jersey.media:jersey-media-moxy:jar:2.22.1:
>   ArtifactResolutionException: Failure to transfer
>   org.glassfish.jersey.media:jersey-media-moxy:pom:2.22.1 from
>   http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local
>   repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update
>   interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced. Original error:
>   Could not transfer artifact
>   org.glassfish.jersey.media:jersey-media-moxy:pom:2.22.1 from/to
>   central

Answer (score 7):

I was able to resolve the issue with below steps:
Right click on the maven project in Eclipse -> Maven -> Update Project -> Check "Force update of snapshots/Releases" check box.

Answer (score 1):

try

```
mvn clean compile -U
```

`-U` will force update all artifact dependencies

Comment: Hi Jigar Joshi, I have created the maven project in Eclipse.

Comment: you could still run maven raw goals through eclipse, `right click on project -> run as -> maven build...`

Answer (score 0):

- There is a option of terminal in tool bar of eclipse.
- open terminal in eclipse and navigate to your eclipse work space( place where your project reside).
- Navigate to the project folder i.e your maven project folder
- Next run **mvn clean**, It will clean all the build which you have for project.
- Next run **mvn compile** this will install all the dependencies mentioned in your pom.xml, if they are not installed.
  restart your server now.